# What is a Heavenly Father? What is spirit-possession in a human being?

Tags: sin, jinn, children, human-body, creatures

If the language of the God-family is disagreeable with the understandings or dogma of Muslim belief, how can I understand the belief that it is possible for a non-human being to possess or inhabit a human being, but it is not possible or true that the Creator of both non and human beings cannot possess or inhabit one of or all of His creatures whenever and however He so wills. Does Islam mean Allah will not inhabit His human being and all of His human beings? How does Islam know the Will of Allah? Is it possible to understand Allah as a and The Heavenly Father, as in the Father of all things and beings?

Answer (score 0):

The term 'Father' is a Christian rather than an Islamic term as in 'Our Father in Heaven' in the Lord's Prayer.

In the sense that the father is a creator, that it his seed that seeds new life, this is simply understood in Islam as *al-Khaliq*, the Creator and is one of the attributes of *Allah*, who is beyond all description. As in *Sura al-An'am* 6:102

> This is Allah - Your Lord! There is no god  worthy of worship except Him. He is the Creator of all things, so worship him alone. And He is the Maintainer of everything.

As for spirit possession, there is possession by jinns.

Comment: Father is also a concept before it is ascribed to a religious expression and therefore can be understood outside of religious expressions. Therefore, I am certain that the Muslim understands Fatherhood. I almost understand that because it is a term embraced in both Judaism and Christianity, Islam will not agree to look at the same thing in the same way. It is clear though to any reasonable person that God as Spirit is therefore the Father of spirits, all spirits and everything spiritual, including Islam. It is ultimately admirable that the Muslim does not venture too far from the term Allah.

Comment: Jinns...if the Muslim concedes that spirit can possess a human body, it seems likely that were it not for religion, the idea that the Father of Spirit can 'take' (or give) possession of a human body would be conceivable and acceptable.